# WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 fails to start with security vault enabled

Tags: security, wso2, esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.9.0 and try to configure the security vault to encrypt passwords, following what is described in the [official guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon441/Securing+Passwords+in+Configuration+Files)

I modified (commented out) lines in file secret-conf.properties and specified secret providers classes.
I let the default values (especially password and JKS for testing)

I run tool ciphertool from bin folder
Passwords in cipher-text.properties have been encrypted
and references in configuration files have been modified with attribute svns:secretAlias="[cipher-text.key]"

I restarted the server, entered the store/key password, and got the following error :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [8004-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:133)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:277)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:133)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:241)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.createSession(SessionRemote.java:219)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:111)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:95)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:429)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:230)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:109)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2016-08-31 12:11:46,829] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:240)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:96)
```

I checked both files ./repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml and ./repository/conf/security/cipher-text.properties, the ciper key matches.

Can you tell me what i've missed ?

Comment: After a couple of hours of testing, i finally succeed to make wso2 esb starting. I have to update file secret-conf.properties file and change the value of property `secretRepositories.file.location`, the path must include folders, i.e. `repository/conf/security/cipher-text.properties`, not `cipher-text.properties` only. Pb solved

Answer (score 0):

In-order to [enable secure vault](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon441/Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool#EncryptingPasswordswithCipherTool-Encryptingpasswordsusingtheautomatedprocess), you need to execute ./cipher-tool.sh (for linux and for windows, it is cipher-tool.bat) with the parameter -Dconfigure which will encrypt the values in cipher-text.properties, add the alias to each conf file using the xpath mentioned in cipher-tool.properies and create the secret-conf.properties file. The newly created secret-conf.properties will contain the values for secretRepositories.file.location, etc...